# Trying to Extract Sections from Nmap Output

Tags: sed, awk, nmap

I have some data from an Nmap Scan.  It looks like this.

```
Nmap scan report for 10.16.17.34
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Not shown: 65530 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
23/tcp   open  telnet
80/tcp   open  http
| http-headers: 
|   Date: THU, 30 AUG 2012 22:46:11 GMT
|   Expires: THU, 30 AUG 2012 22:46:11 GMT
|   Content-type: text/html
|   
|_  (Request type: GET)
443/tcp  open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   SSLv3
|     Ciphers (11)
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5 - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong
|   TLSv1.0
|     Ciphers (10)
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT1024_WITH_RC4_56_SHA - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5 - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5 - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 - unknown strength
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong
|     Compressors (1)
|       NULL
|_  Least strength = unknown strength
2023/tcp open  xinuexpansion3

Nmap scan report for 10.16.40.0
Host is up (0.00062s latency).
All 65535 scanned ports on 10.16.40.0 are closed

Nmap scan report for 10.16.40.1
Host is up (0.00071s latency).
All 65535 scanned ports on 10.16.40.1 are closed
```

What I am attempting to do is to either use Awk, Sed or Grep or something else to extract any section that starts with Nmap Scan and ends in a blank new line and has ssl-enum-ciphers in it.    I figured out with Awk how to print each section but I can't get it to check for the ssl line.   I'm out of my league with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is blank-line separated records. You can use `awk` to check for your ssl-enum-ciphers:

```
awk -v RS='' '/ssl-enum-ciphers/' file.txt
```

---

This will check that the record doesn't contain the phrase 'host down':

```
awk -v RS='' '/ssl-enum-ciphers/ && !/host down/' file.txt
```

You could make this more stringent by changing the field separator to a newline character:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n" } /ssl-enum-ciphers/ && $1 !~ /host down/' file.txt
```

---

Add some newlines between records:

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS=""; FS="\n" } /ssl-enum-ciphers/ && $1 !~ /host down/ { printf "%s\n\n", $0 }' file.txt
```

Comment: That leaves me with some junk but it gets me close enough to what I need.  Thanks

Comment: I ended up with a lot of these "Nmap scan report for 10.16.14.166 [host down]"  for various IP's

Comment: Yea that's clean.   I'll just throw in a few /n between sections and we can start working of that data.  I was close with the BEGIN section but got lost in a print $ statement

Comment: Yep that's what I did.  Thanks.  You've been a big help

Answer (score 0):

Processing Nmap text output is tricky and fraught with dangers, since it can change from version to version. For parsing Nmap output, use the [XML output](http://nmap.org/book/output-formats-xml-output.html) with the `-oX` or `-oA` arguments. Then use an XML parsing library or utility to extract the information you need.

For your example, use [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) to extract the `host` element that contains a `script` element with the `id` attribute set to "ssl-enum-ciphers". This example will output the IP address of the target, followed by the output from the `ssl-enum-ciphers` script:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//script[@id="ssl-enum-ciphers"]' \
-v '../../../address[@addrtype="ipv4"]/@addr' -v '@output' output.xml
```

In the next release of Nmap, script output itself will be further broken into XML structures, making it easier to do things like output a list of only the weak ciphers in use.